# today published book - is this correct?

Tags: word-choice

"The Viennese SAP consultant Daniela Kickl reports in her today published book about her experiences from the Irish service center Apple."

I can't decide if I should write that or

"The Viennese SAP consultant Daniela Kickl reports in her published book today about her experiences from the Irish service center Apple."

I want to say that she reports in her published book which got published today but somehow both sentences feel odd.

Comment: How about "The Viennese SAP consultant Daniela Kickl reports in her book, published today, about her experiences from the Irish service center Apple."?

Comment: book published today....in the Apple service center in Ireland.

Comment: "...reports in her book published today about her experiences..." would be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Viennese SAP consultant Daniela Kickl reports in her today published book about her experiences from the Irish service center Apple.

This is wrong - today is not an adjective. Try

> The Viennese SAP consultant Daniela Kickl reports in her book, published today, about her experiences from the Irish service center Apple.

which is probably what you want, or maybe

> The Viennese SAP consultant Daniela Kickl reports today in her book about her experiences from the Irish service center Apple.

although this one removed the emphasis on publishing.